# Code to, if cell isn't empty, insert a few equations in offset position

Tags: excel, vba

I have found different chunks of the answer in many Google searches and I have smashed them together in the code below, but I'm getting errors and other issues.

I need to scan col P, if there is a value in col P, then offset one row and -12 col and paste in a formula. (In the recorded macro the first value in P is in P43). So in my code I have range as a cell not as an offset reference (if P43 is active cell first equation should go into D44 or R1C-12 etc). I keep getting an error in my `if cell <> ""` statement. This code will have to repeat until it hits the last row (row value is stored in cell "AU1" since there are many gaps in data).

```
Sub DropEq()

Dim dlen2 As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
dlen2 = Worksheets("HR-Calc").Range("AS1")

If Cells(lRow, "P") <> "" Then ActiveCell.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -12).FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(R[-1]C[-3],-R[-1]C[30],0)"

'first instance thats true for statement above  is P43, which would then throw the equations below into those cells
    'Range("d44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(R[-1]C[-3],-R[-1]C[30],0)"

'Range("E44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=COUNTA(R[-1]C[-2]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[-2],-R[-2]C[29],0))/2"

    'Range("F44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF(R[-1]C[-4]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[-4],-R[-2]C[28],0),R1C21,R[-1]C[8]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[8],-R[-2]C[28],0))"

'Range("G44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF(R[-1]C[-5]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[-5],-R[-2]C[27],0),R2C21,R[-1]C[7]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[7],-R[-2]C[27],0))"

'Range("H44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =    "=SUM(R[-1]C[7]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[7],-R[-2]C[26],0))"

'Range("I44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "= COUNTA(R[-1]C[6]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[6],-R[-2]C[25],0))-COUNTBLANK(R[-1]C[6]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[6],-R[-2]C[25],0))"

'   I'd like a msgbox asking single or double fuse? then ask for fuse rating and place input value that into "E45 relative to P43"
'    Range("E45").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "30A STRING"
'    Range("F45").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "POS"
'    Range("G45").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NEG"
'    Range("H45").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MAX SPL"
'    Range("I45").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "# SPL"
 Next lRow


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would look like:

```
Sub DropEq()

Dim dlen2 As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
dlen2 = Worksheets("HR-Calc").Range("AS1")

For lrow = 1 To Cells.Range("AU1").Value
    If Cells(lrow, "P") <> "" Then
        Cells(lrow, "P").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -12).FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(R[-1]C[-3],-R[-1]C[30],0)"
    End If

'first instance thats true for statement above  is P43, which would then throw the equations below into those cells
    'Range("d44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(R[-1]C[-3],-R[-1]C[30],0)"

'Range("E44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=COUNTA(R[-1]C[-2]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[-2],-R[-2]C[29],0))/2"

    'Range("F44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF(R[-1]C[-4]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[-4],-R[-2]C[28],0),R1C21,R[-1]C[8]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[8],-R[-2]C[28],0))"

'Range("G44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF(R[-1]C[-5]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[-5],-R[-2]C[27],0),R2C21,R[-1]C[7]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[7],-R[-2]C[27],0))"

'Range("H44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =    "=SUM(R[-1]C[7]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[7],-R[-2]C[26],0))"

'Range("I44").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "= COUNTA(R[-1]C[6]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[6],-R[-2]C[25],0))-COUNTBLANK(R[-1]C[6]:OFFSET(R[-1]C[6],-R[-2]C[25],0))"

'   I'd like a msgbox asking single or double fuse? then ask for fuse rating and place input value that into "E45 relative to P43"
'    Range("E45").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "30A STRING"
'    Range("F45").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "POS"
'    Range("G45").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NEG"
'    Range("H45").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MAX SPL"
'    Range("I45").ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "# SPL"
Next lrow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, all I had to was adjust the reference location from the active cell in col P. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values in column P are constants, you can try running the following line of code using specialcells and avoid the loop altogether.

```
columns("P").specialCells(xlcelltypeconstants).offset(1,-12).formular1c1="=OFFSET(R[-1]C[-3],-R[-1]C[30],0)"
```

For more on special cells, see [here](https://tduhameau.wordpress.com/tag/specialcells/).

Comment: Col P values are positive numbers and blank " . But I will try this method and let you know if this works for me

Comment: That should work, it's constants vs. formulas, so positive numbers are fine.